# kubectl command | pass the credentials

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubectl

I have Azure DevOps Server, using Yaml pipeline trying to connect On-Prem Tanzu Kubernetes Cluster.

Below is the command using thro Cmdline task,

```
Kubectl.exe vsphere login –server --insecure-skip-tls-verify -u <username> --tanzu-kubernetes-cluster-name
```

But its giving an error kubectl_vsphere_password environment variable missing.

How do i hardcode the password which i have as a variable?

I have tried using Azure devops variable for kubernetes cluster password like -u username:password which is not working

Yaml File:
-task: cmdLine@2
inputs:
scripts: |
(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\Kubectl-vsphere.exe login --
server=UATSERVER --insecure-skip-tls-verify -u
testuser@uatdomain.com --tanzu-kubernetes-clsuter-name uat-
cluster-1 --tanzu-kubernetes-clsuter-namespace uat-
namepsace
env:
Kubectl_Vsphere_password: (pass)

Comment: Please share more of your pipeline. If you've defined an Azure Pipelines variable as a secret type, you need to explicitly map the variable as an environment variable in an `env` block. Refer to the documentation.